# How to fix my nav bar? Positioning is different on different screens

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm kind of new to HTML and CSS. I have a nav bar that I want (the logo and links) aligned to being above the sidebar on my page. It's in different positions on different screens  (and when browser is resized) and I don't know how to fix it. I made a fiddle thing and I'll link to the site so that you will know what I mean. 
**This is the fiddle:** [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqujxb99/1/)

**This is the page:** [The page](http://beta.crazyblock.com/index.html)

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 91px;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#menu {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    height: 54px;
    margin-top: 0;
    background: #ffffff url(http://i1378.photobucket.com/albums/ah105/WinPhanNick/menu_bar_zps6212d723.jpg) repeat-x left top;
    position: fixed;
}
#menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    line-height: normal;
    margin-left: 28%;
}
#menu li {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 36px;
    padding: 18px 20px 0px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
}
li#logo {
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    background: url(http://i1378.photobucket.com/albums/ah105/WinPhanNick/cb_logo_zpsd1b14443.png) no-repeat;
    margin-top: 1px;
    margin-right: 1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
#menu a:hover,
#menu .active a {
    background: #1687ef;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#logo {
    float: left;
    width: 270px;
    height: 76px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 15px 0px 0px;
    margin-left: 27%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your link wrapper (which is the `ul`) the same width as your page container (which is `892px`) and set it to `margin: auto` to center it. You can remove the `margin-left: 28%` as well. That's not needed. You also have a float issue so your `ul` is collapsed. You need to clear your floated elements. You can add `overflow:hidden`.

```
#menu ul{
   overflow: hidden; //clear float issue
   width: 892px; // same width as #page
   margin: 0 auto; //will center
   padding: 0px 30px; //add to keep the same padding as #page-bgtop
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/kqujxb99/2/)